# get_term_children specific no id

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, get-children

hi everyone from the codex I found what I needed that is to show the sub-taxonomies by specifying the id of the sub-taxonomy and the macro taxonomy

```
get_term_children( int $term_id, string $taxonomy )
```

with the example shown

```
<?php
$term_id = 10;
$taxonomy_name = 'products';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

ok and this works perfectly, i was wondering if there was another possibility instead of specifying the id of the sub-taxonomy which is not exactly the best it is possible specifying by writing the name, how could it be done?

to have a typical result

```
<?php
$term_id = 'telephone';
$taxonomy_name = 'products';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I wrote macro and micro only for understanding of question, however the context is "archive" taxonomy or the taxonomy-xxx.php, the problem is that I am in this situation(example) category-> training-> basketball, according to the archive page taxonomy basketball, I would like to let all the training children out and I would not do it with the id

Comment: In what context? The taxonomy archive? Also, please note that there's no such thing as a "sub taxonomy" or "macro". As suggested by the function names, they are called "terms", and terms belong to taxonomies. You can use `get_queried_object_id()` as `$term_id` if the queried object is the term whose children you want to find.

Comment: @JacobPeattie clear I wrote macro and micro only for understanding of question, however the context is "archive" taxonomy or the taxonomy-xxx.php, the problem is that I am in this situation category-> training-> basketball, according to the archive page taxonomy basketball, I would like to let all the training children out and I would not do it with the id

Comment: You should include context like that in the question. The question as written does not provide the information that would be necessary to give you to correct answer.

Comment: @JacobPeattie are you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> the problem is that I am in this situation category-> training->
>   basketball, according to the archive page taxonomy basketball, I would
>   like to let all the training children out and I would not do it with
>   the id

What you're actually trying to do is get all *terms* that are 'siblings' of the current term i.e. terms with the same parent.

You can do this by using the current term's parent ID combined with `get_terms()`, like this:

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();
$siblings     = get_terms(
    [
        'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
        'parent'   => $current_term->parent,
    ]
);

echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $siblings as $sibling ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $sibling ) . '">' . $sibling->name . '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Note that by using `get_terms()`, rather than `get_term_children()`, I avoid the need to use `get_term_by()`.

You can simplify this code even further by using `wp_list_categories()` to output the HTML for a list:

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();

wp_list_categories(
    [
        'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
        'parent'   => $current_term->parent,
    ]
);
```

Comment: I thank you for taking the time but it is not what I ask, probably I am wrong to explain, I put you in the question additional code to make you understand better

Comment: My answer does exactly what your additional information is asking for. Did you even try it?